# A person using dictator identity in profile

Tags: support, chat, users, display-names

Currently a persistent person is creating this user account in various SE sites, and then [joining various chat rooms.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13440774#13440774). RegDwight has run out of moderation options for this. Can devs or other community leaders step in?

**Update:** We how have this: Adofl Hitlar . with same image.

https://askubuntu.com/users/241025/adofl-hitlar

https://askubuntu.com/users/241032/adofl-hitlar

There is some chat history available at the above link.

[Here's the user's current profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/240980/adolf-hitler)

Here are the current profiles with this name/image:

https://askubuntu.com/users/240974/adolf-hitler

https://askubuntu.com/users/240978/adolf-hitler

https://askubuntu.com/users/240980/adolf-hitler

but I expect that to change

Comment: The [2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) currently has like 4-5 Hitlers. Do something!!

Comment: As with any moderation issue, flag a post of theirs and explain the issue in the flag reason.  This isn't something that can be handled by a non-moderator.  Moderators can escalate issues on their own if they need one of their superiors.

Comment: @Servy - the user has not actually **posted** any chat messages.

Comment: He's not posting. His mere presence is irritating.

Comment: @rolfl Then flag a post of his on the main site.  If he has none, flag a random post.

Comment: 0 activity whatsoever, just joining chatroom and leaving, and joining, and leaving, and being AH.

Comment: @Servy I think he doesn't have any posts anywhere.

Comment: Those are something like half a dozen separate chat accounts, that makes it rather annoying to deal with

Comment: @kleinfreund You need a minimal amount of rep to join chat, so it's at least *likely* he has a single post, unless it all came from suggested edits, in which case, as I said, flag a random post instead.

Comment: [A chat profile of his](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/107167/adolf-hitler). The fact that he's in some rooms such as [German.se] is just offensive to some people.

Comment: @Servy Nope, it just takes minimum rep to *talk* in chat.

Comment: Don't they all come from the same IP?

Comment: @Servy - more than one account.....

Comment: @rolfl Again, you can still flag a post and provide links to all related accounts.  There is no need to bring it up publicly and involve a bunch of people that can't do anything about it.

Comment: Probably another TOR attack. Drupal Answers got 2 just last week. Maybe Stack should simply ban TOR and other anonimizers that allows to create many accounts with many IPs fast? Or severely limit possible activities for their users?

Comment: @Servy - ahh.... I understand what you are saying now.... as it happens, I was directed to do this by a mod ... ;-)

Comment: @Servy You can, however that account will be handled, and then another will pop up, it needs to be brought up to the SE team.

Comment: I'm on this. I'll write a proper answer in a bit. He's definitely using proxies / tor / mobile networks. Coincidentally, it's Holocaust memorial day so ... how wonderful of him to spend it with us.

Comment: @hichris123 And the appropriate way to do that is to flag the post.  Say exactly that in the flag message, and the mod can contact whomever they need to.

Comment: @Servy: I really don't see the problem with bringing up issues which need an urgent response/ attention up on Meta. Yes, there's the *by the book, technically correct, blah blah blah* way, then there are the exceptions. This is one of them.

Comment: Same image content but a different image URL for each one.

Comment: @Servy So, only issues where all members of SE can do something about it instead of mods can be brought to meta?

Comment: Great, we got Bin Laden now

Comment: @ChrisW that's because he's uploading it again each time, it's hosted on imgur

Comment: Now [Osama Bin Laden](http://askubuntu.com/users/240987/osama-bin-laden) has joined...

Comment: @Matt 1) Flagging is generally going to be the faster way of getting a moderator's attention 2) there's no need to be publicly bringing up issues that should be private 3) none of us can actually *do* anything about it to help, it's wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Servy "issues that should be private"? If the user was using their real name I can see why you should think twice before bringing it to meta and calling them out publicly but presumably doesn't apply here!

Comment: @Lamak Correct.  If you have an issue about which you wish to speak to a mod privately about you should either flag, or use the "contact us" option, rather than creating a meta post to discuss a private issue publicly.

Comment: @Servy Why does this warrant a private situation, though? It doesn't compromise any user privacy/security stuff...

Comment: @Servy: 1) We don't need the attention of a moderator in this situation, we need the attention of an SE member of staff. When you flag a post, you get the attention of mods on a single site. Posting on meta gets the attention of all mods and SE staff which are active on the site, giving us much more chance of finding *someone* who can contact *someone*. 2) There's no reason why this should be private. 3) This isn't about *us* doing anything about it. It's about getting the attention of the right people ASAP, which is what this has achieved.

Comment: @Servy 3) none of us can actually do anything <- That deserves a solid meta discussion

Comment: is there some way to convert this to a CW post or something? I'm not thrilled if my MSO rep is expanding because of this....

Comment: @Servy I never asked about wanting to talk about an issue with a mod privately, that was you. I'm talking about why do you think that meta discussion must be only about issues where everyone can do something about it, do you have a link to support what you are saying?

Comment: Post converted to CW... thanks.

Comment: If you want to feel better about the rep, start +100 bounty on something you hold dear here on Meta.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard I'll do that, and perhaps find a place for the `You've earned the "Nice Question" badge for Adolf Hitler user and Icon. See your profile.` badge ;-)

Comment: The obvious thing to do is flood the chat room with other villains. Ming the Merciless, Sauron, Lex Luther, Shere Kahn, L. Borgia, MacBeth and so on. Drown the signal in noise and dilute it's impact with fiction. ... Goldfinger, Dr. No, Dr. Evil, Arms Akimbo ...

Comment: @rolfl I fear badges can't be given away, wear it proudly!

Comment: Hmmm.. the only *wearable badges* I know of, are trapped in boxes until next WinterBash...

Comment: @TimPost FYI: http://askubuntu.com/users/241025/adofl-hitlar

Comment: And also: http://askubuntu.com/users/241032/adofl-hitlar

Comment: @TimPost Not to be technical but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_Memorial_Days), Holocaust Memorial Day was yesterday. He's late! (One occasion where "Better later than never" **does not apply**)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I do recall seeing meta posts yesterday on some sites that were getting auto-posted by the various feed that then showed up in the chat room (with icon).  The one I recall seeing yesterday was from Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Follow-on question: [Flag offensive user profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217778/flag-offensive-user-profile) concerning debate about what the *right thing* is to do when this happens.

Comment: But what if [this poor kid](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/northamerica/usa/10097369/Father-who-called-one-son-Adolf-Hitler-dresses-as-Nazi-for-court-hearing-over-visitation-rights-for-youngest-child.html) one day decides to peruse the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: @Pëkka - Then he had better choose a different picture.... ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard +100 bounty applied to [Flag Offensive user profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217778/flag-offensive-user-profile) - Fight fire with fire ;-)

Comment: @rolfl cheers, that's not quite what I had in mind (was thinking more of some old bug report or feature request that needs bumping) but it's also good. :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is something we're aware of, and currently mitigating. We do have some rather comprehensive facilities in place to handle this sort of thing, however I consider this person to be highly competent and you'll probably see them surface some more before it ends.

I've got some changes to send over regarding how chat is wired up to the spam / abuse mitigation layer that we have in place, some loopholes for abuse became apparent during this. I'm giving that priority and will get it over to the devs to investigate shortly.

Until this fully subsides - ***do not give this person the attention that they crave.*** Flag, move on and otherwise ignore them. The moderators have clear instructions on what to do, bear with us while we work with them to handle it.

Comment: Just curious, has this person attacked before? Or is this his first time?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's rather impossible to say for certain. If this person has trolled our sites before, this is the first time they did it wearing a dead Nazi.

Comment: OK, just thought you might recognize patterns or proxy servers the user is using etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's what I need to figure out a better way of doing. We're tracking an _amazing_ amount of 'ghettos' where these things and people seem to flourish, but association with them is a very weak signal to analyze - a notch lower than faint really. I _definitely_ see patterns when it comes to how they move around the network but the data is just so .. bland, there's not much I can get from it. What's _really_ interesting is looking at patterns in the actual _requests_ that they make, kind of like DNA for spam bots. Humans? Less interesting, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, so they're just bots?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, this particular one was human, though he could have been using something automated to help him.

Comment: @TimPost Teach [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11622164/hitler-jr10) too what is no-no. There is no need for nicks like that in this community. Thanks.