# How can we deal with network-wide abuse more effectively? (And: a call to action)

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, abuse

A certain user has been posting this on multiple SE sites:

> I WANT CREATE NEW OS BUT NOT LINUX I NEED CREATE BY UNIX SO IT IS
> CLEAN MAYBE A LIGTER KERNEL ...
>
> IW WILL CREATE REMOTE OS WHERE IT BEGINS OFF WITH YOUR BODY AND AFTER
> START UP WHEN YOU BACK HOME ...
>
> THEN WILL ALSO MAKE CUSTOM TEMPLATE LIKE ICEWM ...........
>
> WILL POSSIBILY MAKE CUSTOM PROGRAM LIKE VLC MEDIA PLAYER FIREFOX
> BROWSER AND I WANT LIKE ANDROID SO ITS LITE BUT WANT TO GAVE ANOTHER
> NAME ...
>
> THIS IS POSSIBLE?? HOW IF SO?????????
>
> THANK YOU VERRY MUCH GAYS   PRADESH DAJA!!!!!!!

[Exhibit A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/8a4374c0-650f-497a-a1cc-6d1aaf3a0e59/view-source), [Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f3b63a80-429b-407d-9549-49e58a1df470/view-source), [Exhibit C](https://superuser.com/revisions/7b81b224-3bdc-40e9-926e-0aa1b692dd5d/view-source)

The comments are just as bad (from [here](https://superuser.com/q/709801/218034)):

Screenshot 1:

> [image]

Screenshot 2:

> [image]

So, my question is, how do we deal with this kind of abuse? Could we get a new feature, perhaps? (A network-wide ban would be amazing, but I doubt that will exist any time soon :P)

Also, this is a call to action - [watch out for questions like this on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) and please flag the two that are still alive ([A](https://superuser.com/q/709801/218034), [B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111927/45600)).

Comment: In all honesty, by not feeding the troll. Admittedly, I have been interacting with him way too long. Just vote to close or flag. They will run out of steam soon enough. And if it really gets out of hand, just use a custom flag with some extra info so it can be escalated to someone on the team if necessary.

Comment: We're coordinating on this in the TL. I think we've destroyed four of their accounts now. At first, they looked legit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218216/lost-access-to-my-account-but-i-remember-the-password-and-user-name , then they started going far enough off the rails that it flipped the "troll" bit. Hopefully, the new anti-spam system will pick them up if they try to post again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just lost it at `I NO MUCH MONEY YOU UNDERSTAND??!`. I don't understand what these people think they're accomplishing with these posts...

Comment: There is already a network wide suspension, see [this profile](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17574/tony-stewart?tab=summary) for example. Unless you mean network wide account deletion? This too probably exists for devs.

Comment: Two related recent meta questions: [Flag offensive user profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217778/flag-offensive-user-profile) and [A person using dictator identity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217740/a-person-using-dictator-identity-in-profile) (Related because of simply being other kinds of network abuse, perhaps it could be solved in the same way somehow -- by flagging a user profile for example)

Comment: Fwiw, odd that the question filter doesn't catch all-caps posts.

Comment: The fake ungrammatical English is pretty good, but it's still clearly fake. This is just someone getting his jollies wasting other people's time.